# ostream fails to open the file because of too many open Files

Tags: c++, ostream

The  following is the function that I call it once! As I can see it opens the file once!
But I can't understand why it returns "Too many open files". Does it have anything related to the size of my vector?

```
void WriteResult(std::vector<result*> result)
{
    std::string tempStr = "";
    std::string outPath = "/my/path/similarityScores.txt" ;
    for ( int i=0; i< result.size(); i++)
        tempStr += (*result[i]).GetResult();
    outStream.open(outPath.c_str(), std::ios::app );
    if (!outStream)
        std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';  
    outStream << tempStr;
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: You have most likely opened files which you haven't closed before you get to `WriteResult`.

Answer (score 0):

`Too many open files` is an issue with the computer (there is a per-user and a global limit to how many files can be open at once)  you can use a program like `lsof` to see what files are open currently.

Try restarting your machine and run the program again.

Comment: `Too many open files` can be an OS limit, but most of the time, it's a program limit; somewhere, the program is opening a file, and failing to close it.

Comment: But the tip with lsof is still valid. Maybe the OP really has too many files open (similar to a memory leak), or maybe another application messed up. This will most likely point out the culprit.

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
for ( int i=0; i< result.size(); i++)
**{**tempStr += (*result[i]).GetResult();**}**
outStream.open(outPath.c_str(), std::ios::app );
```

Btw, think about replacing "for" with "for_each" stl method